# Problem with Beamer, environments, and \if

Tags: beamer, environments, conditionals

The following code will not compile and I am mystified:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\newif\ifTest
\Testtrue
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\ifTest
\begin{center}
content
\end{center}
\fi
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the `fragile` option if you want to use such low-level tests:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\newif\ifTest
\Testtrue
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{title}
\ifTest
\begin{center}
content
\end{center}
\fi
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you!  worked like a charm.  If you don't mind, what did you mean by "low-level test"?  is there a superior way to create different versions of the same slides?